# How to query remote index catalogs

Tags: sql-server, indexing, catalog

I've been trying to create a linked server in SQL Server that accesses a
remote Index Service catalog, but I can't seem to do it. Let's call
the remote server "remoteServer" and the Catalog "remoteCatalog"

I've tried this:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver remoteIndexServer, 'Index Server', 'MSIDXS',
    'query://remoteServer/remoteCatalog'
```

and then i did run the SQL

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(remoteIndexServer,'select filename from scope()') AS Q
```

But i got the error as

```
OLE DB provider "MSIDXS" for linked server "remoteIndexServer" returned message "Service is not running. ".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot execute the query "select filename from scope()" against OLE DB provider "MSIDXS" for linked server "remoteIndexServer".
```

Comment: Is the remote server running?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue before. This is from memory so excuse any errors but if I recall correctly you will need to do the following.

Install the indexing service on your local SQL Server (this is so the provider is available).

Add a linked server to this `LOCAL` indexing service.

You can then run you query as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM   OPENQUERY(
           LocalLinkedServer,
           'select filename from RemoteServer.CatalogName..scope()'
       ) AS Q
```

If that doesn't work let me know, there is a post somewhere that describes how to do this. I can look it up if necessary but I think the above is right.